# How do you use data that was passed into a component in a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, use-state

I have a functional component that has been passed data ({clicked}) from its parent function, but when I try to use it as a variable in my function, it errors out. Here is my current code:

```
function Songs({clicked}) {

    const songListFiltered = songList.filter(item => item.{clicked} === true) 
    const songDisplayed = songListFiltered[Math.floor(Math.random() * songListFiltered.length)] 
    return (
        <div className="song-box">
            <img src={songDisplayed.artwork} alt="album artwork" />
            <h3>{songDisplayed.songName}</h3>
            <p>{songDisplayed.artistName}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I need to check if songList has the data in {clicked}, in order to filter those songs from the list, but I'm not sure how to make it work. Would love any help!

Comment: `item.{clicked}` is not valid javascript, perhaps you meant `item[clicked]`? But without knowing the shape of your data and what `clicked`  holds it's hard to say.

Comment: clicked is a function that holds a string as its value from useState

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the shape of your data, you would invoke this different ways.
The variable `{clicked}` would be an object with key value pairs, so you would need to use it as `clicked.yourCustomValue`.  If it's an array, you would use the index, so `item.clicked[0]`, and if clicked is a function, you would need to invoke it with `clicked()`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the statement

> I need to check if songList has the data in {clicked}

And based on the code

> songList.filter(item => item.{clicked} === true)

i assume that the variable `{clicked}` would be an array containing a collection of song objects that have been selected by the user, and the data type of the `songList` variable is an array containing song objects

So, you can replace the variable songListFiltered with

```
const songListFiltered = songList.filter(function (e) {
    let result = [];
    for (let songClicked of clicked) {
      if (e.songName === songClicked.songName) {
        result.push(e);
      }
    }
    return result.length === 0 ? null : result;
  });
```

Or if you mean `{clicked}` is a property that you add to the each of songList object when you have selected a song, then you can use `typeof` when checking the condition filter. Then, the code could be as follows `songList.filter(item => typeof(item.clicked) !== "undefined")`

[Array filtering element](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-array-filter/?msclkid=32fcaff5afe411ec8fdb758713e8c45b)
[Array contains check](https://appdividend.com/2022/03/08/javascript-array-includes/#:%7E:text=Javascript%20array%20contains.%20To%20check%20if%20an%20array,an%20array%20consists%20of%20an%20object%20in%20JavaScript.?msclkid=494c5856afe711ec8bc3297641794258)